# Is possible to add a proxy after creating ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

Normally adding options to the chromedriver is easy.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("163.172.125.151:3128");
proxy.setSslProxy("163.172.125.151:3128");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

wDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

//Deprecated..

I am looking for a way to add the proxy after I created the chromedriver like

ChromeOptions options = driver.getOptions();

is there anything like this? or is it possible to add proxy in runtime without any extensions?

Comment: Why can't you set it before?

Comment: @AndiCover I need it in runtime. Because lets think about requesting a url too much, then you get a captcha.

Comment: You could create a new driver instance everytime you want to change the proxy.

Comment: @AndiCover yeah just replacing old one with the new one. I hope that there can be an easier solution, But I think not..

Comment: You could have your proxy change it's upstream proxy